# prevent angular from recursively loading component

Tags: angular, recursion, angular-dynamic-components

I'm loading component dynamically into dynamic position and since that component is a table row I'm using `selector: 'td'` because I need to apply `colspan` to the dynamically add row then load the dynamic component in it.
The problem is my component is a table which contains `<td>` tags and these tags causing angular into going into infinity recursive loop!

What are my alternatives?

I have looked at few ways on how recursive component working but couldn't figure a way to stop angular from thinking this that the tag isn't needed
Tried to use `*ngTemplateOutlet` but got lost

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'td',
  template: `
  <div style="background:red">
    <td>Mark</td> <!-- This is the problem! -->
  </div>
  `,
  host: {
      "[attr.colspan]": "3", 
   },
})
```

If preventing isn't possible what are my other options? I was thinking of replacing `<td>` with `<div>` !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't replace `td` with `div` and don't override standard html tags! What if you import a component and that component use `td` or `div` too?  Do you really want it to be replaced with your template? That would break everything! Just use another name (maybe with a namespace like `app-td`) or use an attribute to distinguish it:

```
selector: 'td[custom]'
```

and then use it like:

```
<td custom></td>
```

Comment: Definitely the good answer. [It's even in the style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#component-selectors), should one care to read it.

Comment: Thanks, by replacing I meant the td inside my table not the selector then apply a style to it. I also forgot to attach https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-row-components-for-smart-table

Anyway using ``selector: 'td[custom]'`` solved it! thanks heaps